# How to apply jQuery events to a content that is dynamically loaded using an Ajax get request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

This is the jQuery I want the put in the content I am requesting when the page load:

```js
$(".allComments").hide();

$(".viewAll").click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 150) {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
  console.log("view all commment is click")
  $(this).parent().siblings('div.allComments').slideToggle();


})
```

So when the content loads, I want to hide the comment section and the user will be able to press a button to reveal the comments..

the problem is the jQuery is not taking into effects....
I know we can use the **jQuery on() event** but I do not know to use it, if I want the hide the comments when the page loads..

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Let me know if I got it right: you're loading the comments from an AJAX call and you want a button to hide them?

Comment: I want the comments to be automatically be hidden when the page is loaded and the button will show the comments when clicked..:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Load dynamic content
$(document).ready(function(){
  var comments = '';
  for(var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
    comments += '<div>('+i+') Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.</div>';
  }  
  $('#comment-section').append(comments).hide();
});

// View all button click
$(document).on('click','#view-all',function(){
  $('#comment-section').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="comment-section"></div>
<button id="view-all">View All</button>
```